# fbdev fails and crashes to resume if screen is rotated

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, xorg

I have rotated Xorg with following option in xorg.conf

**Option "rotate" "CW"**

After suspend resume(mem statndby mode) Xserver fails and crashes with following debug.

```
[2624355.098] (EE) FBDEV(0): FBIOPUT_VSCREENINFO succeeded but modified mode
[2624355.098] 
Fatal server error:
[2624355.098] EnterVT failed for screen 0
[2624355.098] 
[2624355.098] (EE) 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
     at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
[2624355.098] (EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
[2624355.098] (EE) 
[2624355.128] Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
```

Have anyone faced similar issue with Xorg in rotation ? How to prevent Xorg crash in rotation mode (Option "rotate" "CW") ?